# Bootstrap broker disconnected => KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topcis/xxxx/partitions/2/state + Key no found

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to run kafka-console-consume.sh for a topic XXX

```
sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server abcd:9092, bcde:9092, cdef:9092 --topic XXX
```

below error appear:

> WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrapbroker abcd:9092 disconnected
>
> WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrapbroker bcde:9092 disconnected
>
> WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrapbroker cdef:9092 disconnected

When I check in the broker log, no error except below warning:

> WARN nl.techop.kafka.dao.zookeeper.KafkaZkClient: KeeperErrorCode =
>   NoNode for /brokers/topics/XXX/partitions/2/state WARN
>   com.yammer.metrics.reporting.MetricsServlet: Error evaluating gauge
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: [XXX,0]

#### What I have tried:

I created a testing123 topic successfully with below:

```
    sh kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper defg:2181, dfde:2181, cdef:2181
--replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic testing123
```

#### however when I try with kafka-console-producer.sh, same error happen:

```
sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list abcd:9092, bcde:9092, cdef:9092
```

> WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrap broker abcd:9092 disconnected
>    WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrap broker bcde:9092 disconnected
>   WARN clients.NetworkClient: Botstrap broker cdef:9092 disconnected

Comment: I assume that you have enabled authentication, right?

Comment: `kafka-console-producer` requires you specify a `--topic`... Please show the full command, and you really only need one server to connect to, not all are required. However, you should make sure Kafka is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

The cluster is Kerberos Enabled.

I got the issue resolved by adding the below to my consumer.config properties file:

- group.id = flume
  security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
  ssl.client.auth=none

and run below:

```
sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server abcd:9092, bcde:9092, cdef:9092 --topic XXX --consumer.config /xxx/xxx/xxx/consumer.config.properties
```